# Upload dataframe to already created table in database with specific data types

Tags: sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

1 -
I have a dataframe in `pandas`; a table in `ms sql` with primary keys and specific column types. The connection to data is established with `sqlalchemy`.
When I use `to_sql` method to upload dataframe with `if_exists='replace'` the data is uploaded, but all the primary keys, and column data types are lost. Everything becomes `varchar(max)`, which I don't want. When I use `if_exists='append'`, jupyter notebook crashes. I made sure the int type is `int8` in the dataframe, because I use `tinyint` in ms sql, but that also did not solve the problem.

2 -
How can we upload data with pandas `to_sql` method into a **new table** with specific column types? So how can we specify tinyint, smallint, primary keys etc.?

*I use pandas version 0.22 and anaconda 5.1 (The most up-to-date as of Feb 2018)*